# Only One Data Retrieved -Query String Paramater through link -php/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 8 column: no_faktur (Invoice No), nama_supplayer (Supplier Name), tanggal (Date), kode_barang (Item ID), nama_barang (Item Name), qty (Quantity), harga_beli (Price), and jumlah (total).

I am trying to pass a query string when the user click a link. Second page will retrieve and display any product when user click an invoice number. Link I used is `href=tampil_faktur.php?no_faktur=".$data["no_faktur"]`. Here is the complete code of the first page:

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM faktur GROUP BY no_faktur";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo ("<tr><td>".$data['no_faktur'].
              "</td><td>".$data['nama_supplayer'].
              "</td><td>".$data['tanggal'].
              "</td><td><a href=tampil_faktur.php?no_faktur=".$data["no_faktur"].">View</a>".
              "</td></tr>");
    }
?>
```

And the second page:

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

if(isset($_GET["no_faktur"]))
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM faktur WHERE no_faktur = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["no_faktur"])."';";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

    if($data)
    {
    echo ("<tr><td>".$data['no_faktur'].
          "</td><td>".$data['nama_supplayer'].
          "</td><td>".$data['tanggal'].
          "</td><td>".$data['kode_barang'].
          "</td><td>".$data['nama_barang'].
          "</td><td>".$data['qty'].
          "</td><td>".$data['harga_beli'].
          "</td><td>".$data['jumlah'].
          "</td></tr>");
    }
    else
    {
    echo("<h3 style=\"color: red;\">Nomor faktur ".$_GET["no_faktur"]." didn't found</h3>");
    }
}
else
{
echo("<h3 style=\"color: red;\">Tidak ada produk yang ditampilkan</h3>");
}

?>
```

The query and connection work perfectly. The problem is it only retrieve one product while the invoice number I called contains several product.

My database structure is something like this:

> Invoice No  |  Supplier  |  Date  |  ItemID  |  ItemName  |  Qty  | 
>   Price  |  Total
>
> F0001       |  ABC       |  21/2  |  002     |  Prod1     |  2    | 
>   20     |  40
>
> F0001       |  ABC       |  21/2  |  031     |  Prod2     |  5    | 
>   40     |  200

Thanks.

Comment: use a `<form>` with `method="GET"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and change the code in second page.....

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

if(isset($_GET["no_faktur"]))
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM faktur WHERE no_faktur = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["no_faktur"])."';";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);  //Added from this line to whileloop.. Why because Each product is one row ...
 if($count)
    {
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
   {
    echo ("<tr><td>".$data['no_faktur'].
          "</td><td>".$data['nama_supplayer'].
          "</td><td>".$data['tanggal'].
          "</td><td>".$data['kode_barang'].
          "</td><td>".$data['nama_barang'].
          "</td><td>".$data['qty'].
          "</td><td>".$data['harga_beli'].
          "</td><td>".$data['jumlah'].
          "</td></tr>");
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo("<h3 style=\"color: red;\">Nomor faktur ".$_GET["no_faktur"]." didn't found</h3>");
    }
}
else
{
echo("<h3 style=\"color: red;\">Tidak ada produk yang ditampilkan</h3>");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array of items then you need to use a foreach loop to loop through the data.

I hope this gives you an idea. I am answering from my phone otherwise would have been more detailed.

Comment: @AlonEitan It is an attempt to answer, even if it is a bad attempt.

Comment: @Daedalus Very bad attempt. Anyway, the user delete and then undelete this "answer" so my flag is marked as helpful... Perhaps someone else will flag it again